# Proving that there does/does not exist an ideal of a ring isomorphic to the congruence classes of integers mod 7/5.

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

I hope you can help me with this question. (I apologise for my lack of Latex ability, perhaps someone would be kind enough to edit?)

I'm given the ring $$R = \{a + b \sqrt{-3} \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \}.$$ I first had to show it was neither a PID or UFD which I managed easily enough.
Next however, I had to show that there WAS an ideal I such that R/I was isomorphic to Z7, but that there DOES NOT exist an ideal J such that R/J is isomorphic to Z5 .

Thoughts:
First idea was to consider an ideal of the form where I look at the congruences of a and b mod a certain integer (here, obviously 4 and 3). However I stopped this pretty quickly once I realised that:
 1. I couldn't find a map in the 7 case.
 2. It appeared to me that there was no reason that if this was valid in the 7 case, that it wouldn't work in the 5 case.

So I dismissed that quickly. Next, I looked at absolute values (or rather, their squares), and I considered an ideal of a similar form. However, I found that I could construct numbers with all possible residues mod 5 of their square of abs value, so I dismissed this also, as this indicated to me (perhaps incorrectly?) that this would be valid for the 5 case if it were for 7.

So with this, I'm pretty stuck. My only thought is maybe that this has something to do with the fact that I can construct an element in R with square of absolute value 7 but not 5? Does it? Maybe not.

I hope you guys can help me out, thanks.

Comment: Please check whether my edit reflects your intent.

Comment: It does, thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $\,\ x^2+3 = 0\ $ has a solution in $\,R\,$ so if $\,\Bbb R/I \cong Z_5,\, $ this solution maps to a solution in $\,\Bbb Z_5,\,$ which is impossible, since $\,-3\,$ is not a square in $\,\Bbb Z_5.$

For the second, to force $\,\color{#c00}{7\in I}\,$ it suffices for $\,I\,$ to contain an element of norm $\,7.\,$ Then, writing $\, w = \sqrt{-3},$ we know $I$ contains $\, w^2+3-\color{#c00}7 = w^2-4 = (w-2)(w+2),\,$ therefore $I$ contains either $\,w-2\,$ or $\,w+2,\,$ since $I$ is prime (by $R/I = \Bbb Z_7$ is a field). Can you find a maximal ideal containing such?

Comment: I know that the ideal of elements such that their norm is a multiple of root(7) is an ideal containing this, but I don't know how to find one that is maximal. In fact, that was what I thought before so I don't think I'm considering this correctly. Sorry, I feel a little clueless here

Comment: @ConorTHD Can you give a set of generators for the ideal you mention?  What happens when you take the quotient by this ideal?  What needs to happen for it to be a maximal ideal?

Comment: @ConorTHD By above, we know that $I\supseteq J = (7,w\pm2) = (w)\,$ by $\,ww' = 7.\,$ Notice that, mod $J$ we have $\, 7\equiv 0,\ w\equiv \mp 2,\,$ so every element of $R/J$ is congruent to an integer mod $7$. So $R/J\cong \Bbb Z/7$ or $0$. To exclude the latter requires showing that $1\not\in I.$

Comment: Sorry, I never got back to this. Just wanted to mark it as answered (got it out afterwards) Thanks for the help